# How to get jenkins environment variables from inside java?

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have created a java program to do a ssh connection and do a file transfer using scp. I have added username, hostname and password as environment variables in jenkins. I need to access the value of these environment variables inside my java program.

I tried using the below options inside my java file, but it did not work.

```
System.getProperty("HOSTNAME");
System.getenv("HOSTNAME");
```

I cannot use EnvironmentInjectorPlugin due to some security issues. Could you please point me in the right direction.

Comment: How do you run your java app? Please provide your Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: @AlexeyPrudnikov Thanks for your reply Alex. I got this to work by passing the parameters from Maven: Goals and Options "-DHOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME} -DUSERNAME=${USERNAME} -DPASSWORD=${PASSWORD} clean install test" and retrieved the value from java file as "String strUserName = System.getProperty("USERNAME");". The value inside ${' '} is actually environmental variables declared in jenkins config.

Comment: You are completely right, java app doesn't know about Jenkins environment variables by its own, so you must pass that variables to JVM via `-D` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work by passing the parameters from the Build Step > Maven > Goals and Options,

**Maven: Goals and Options**

```
-DHOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME} -DUSERNAME=${USERNAME} -DPASSWORD=${PASSWORD} -q clean install test
```

and retrieved the value from java file as

```
String strUserName = System.getProperty("USERNAME");
```

The value inside ${' '} is actually environmental variables declared in jenkins config.